# Pasar array ajax al controlador laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax, sesiones

Hola me gustaría si hay alguna forma mas rápida de poder pasar un array en ajax para tratarlo en el controlador.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "borrarSessiones",
    dataType: 'text',
    success : function (response)
    {   
        for (var i = 0 ; i<tfactura.length ; i++){
           var nombre2 = tfactura[i];
           var cantidad = tcantidad[i];
           var precio = tprecio[i];
           $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "factura1",
             data: {nombre2: nombre2, cantidad: cantidad, precio: precio},
             dataType: 'json'
          });
      }
    }
});
```

Asi es como la estoy enviando pero me gustaria enviar los 3 arrays a la vez para no llamar por cada posiion del array llamar a esta funcion de mi controlador porque me esta dando fallos y no se si es porque lo hago 1 a 1 .

```
 public function factura1(Request $request){
     $precio = $request->precio;
     $nombre = $request->nombre2;
     $cantidad = $request->cantidad;

     $request->session()->push('nombres', $nombre);
     $request->session()->push('precios2', $precio);
     $request->session()->push('cantidades', $cantidad);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar datos al servidor, debes usar el método POST en lugar del GET

Luego ya es cuestión de formatear el contenido en JSON:_

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "factura1", 
    data: JSON.stringify({nombre: tfactura, cantidad: tcantidad, precio: tprecio}), 
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exacto prueba enviando POST, te propongo lo realices en JS Vanilla para perder la dependencia a JQuery.

Con la función **JSON.stringify** formateas el objeto en string para enviarlo, luego cuando lo recibes debes volver a convertirlo a JSON con json_decode().

Espero te animes a JS Vanilla, exitos.

```
fetch("borrarSessiones", {
   method: "GET" //Esto no es obligatorio colocarlo, por default toma GET
})
  .then( () => {
     fetch("factura1", {
       method: "POST",     
       body: JSON.stringify({nombre: tfactura, cantidad: tcantidad, precio: tprecio}), 
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
     })
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(respuesta => {
          //Aqui lo q necesites realizar
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
       })
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
```